# Cannot Connect To SQL Within Azure Network

Tags: sql-server, networking, azure

I am having a real hard time establishing SQL connection between servers within a Azure network.  The really odd thing is that I can connect to SQL from my home machine which is outside the VM network.  It seems like some type of network issue from within the VM domain which I have not been able to identify yet.

My configuration is as follows:

- I have three VM's (Active Directory, Sql Server, and an App Server)
- I am trying to establish SQL connection from app server to sql server
- Both VM's Windows Server 2012
- All servers are on the same azure network, affinity group, domain
- All servers connected to the domain and have IP's
- I can see DNS is resolving because I can ping the sql server from the app server using the sql server's computer name
- I created Firewall rules allowing in/out on port 1433 on both servers
- SQL Server is listening on the default port because of this command executed on the SQL Server (i'm not understanding the 0.0.0.0 IP though which may be a problem) (I can connect from home so I think this is ok)

  netstat -an | find ":1433"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING

  TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0          LISTENING
- I created public & private endpoints on SQL for default sql port 1433
- I can actually connect to SQL Server from my home machine
- I have temporarily turned off firewalls on both servers
- tracert from the app server looks like this.

  tracert spsql01

  Tracing route to spsql01 [10.0.0.7]

  over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  4     5 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  spsql01 [10.0.0.7]

  Trace complete.
- On the App Server i create a connection.udl file to test the connection to my SQL Server but it never passes the connection test.
  [image: Failed Connection]

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the appropriate Windows Azure SQL Database firewall rules for your VMs in Windows Azure? You can use either the special 0.0.0.0 for all of Windows Azure or, better, provide the public VIP of your IaaS cloud service (not the private DIP of the individual VMs). The latter limits firewall access to only your cloud service, since the outbound connection to WASD will use your public VIP. Note that if you delete (or stop/deallocate) all the VMs in your cloud service you will lose the VIP.

Comment: Does this recomendation still apply if my SQL server is not a SQL Azure Database.  It is Win Server 2012 running SQL server.  Thanks for the help

Comment: No. Everything I said applies only to Windows Azure SQL Database NOT SQL Server in a VM. If all the servers are on the same VNET then you should be able to access SQL Server using its private DIP without going through the public VIP - i.e., you should not (need) to expose a public endpoint on the cloud service. There is an example in the Windows Azure Training Kit of accessing SQL Server from a PaaS front end using a VNET - this should show you the steps you need to take to open the SQL Server VM to other servers on the VNET.

Comment: I still have this problem after recreating the VM's.  I posted similar question on serverfault http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429340/cannot-connect-to-sql-within-azure-network

Comment: Could it be that an incorrect alias is set up on the app server? I ran into that using AutoSPInstaller http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/workitem/19412 You can edit sql aliases with cliconfg.exe